# Macbook 15,1 frequently crashes during video chat. How can I debug this?

Tags: video, crash, kernel-panic, facetime, google-hangouts

Frequently, and for no apparent reason, my Macbook Pro 15,1 (15-inch, 2019) with macOS 10.14.6 freezes, then hard-crashes during video chats (hangouts, slack, FaceTime). I have not seen this problem during regular video playback (Youtube, VLC). The error report is attached at the bottom.

I had hoped it has to do with integrated graphics switching, but turning it off didn't prevent it from happening.

Can someone parse some useful info from this crash report?

https://pastebin.com/raw/9zTnntxv (too large to paste here, unfortunately).

Comment: Seems to be a problem noted [by others](https://mrmacintosh.com/10-14-6-update-causes-kernel-panic-when-using-facetime-camera/) but with no resolution at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful info from the crash report is simply that it is not your main macOS system that crashed. It is the bridgeOS running on your T2 chip that has crashed. The T2 on your system is, amongst other things, responsible for image processing for the integrated camera.

Therefore it does not seem that looking into the GPU, integrated graphics switching or similar will have an effect on the problem. This seems very likely to be an Apple bug, which will be hard to avoid triggering. In other words - you'll need to downgrade/upgrade the OS on the T2 to get this fixed.

I would advise reaching out to Apple to report the matter, and hope for a speedy upgrade from them that fixes this.

Comment: The "solution" to the problem is not to use the webcam.

Answer (score 1):

This problem disappeared after some OS update (within the same major OS version, I'm still on 10.14.6). So in case anyone still experiences this, try to install all updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue (I have suffered with the same problems since March 2019), you should contact your Apple service center or file a complain to your country's Apple importer and ask to conduct an independent examination of your Macbook to get a confirmation of hardware issues with your Macbook.

Then you can get your money back or sue Apple in your country of residence.

Comment: I sincerely doubt a hardware defect is grounds to sue a manufacturer unless they refuse to repair it.

Comment: @oarfish They even refuse to admin there's an issue. I was unable to reproduce the issue (it's completely non-deterministic) and had to leave my Macbook at service for them to run tests. And no wonder they act like nothing happens inside their service room. Though the Macbook kept crashing 3 times a day for almost a year.